# Stuck with "You are in emergency mode. "

Tags: boot, 22.04, fsck

I cannot boot into my Ubuntu 22.04 machine (Dell OptiPlex 7050), and I repeatedly see the following message on a black screen:

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot", "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press enter for maintenance
or press Control-D to continue.
```

I know I am not the first one complaining about this message, but I cannot found a solution.

I have also seen this:

```
Reloading system manager configuration
Starting default target
Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical .target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
```

But the culprit may be the file system. I have run:

```
journalctl -xb
```

...and found several lines with:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda sector...
Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block...
(...)
ata1: EH complete
systemd-fsck[864]: fsck failed with exit status 4.
systemd-fsck[864]: Running request emergency.target/start/start/replace
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by ... Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
(...)
A start job for unit ureadahead-stop.service has finished successfully
```

The command completes with:

```
A start job for unit ...service has finished successfully.
```

Cannot find anything unusual in `/etc/fstab`.

How to get out of this situation?

Comment: `fsck failed with exit status 4` means it failed to correct errors on the filesystem. Looks like your `sda` disk has an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks now solved. Just with:

```
fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

Comment: fsck -M (do not check mounted filesystems), then yes to "inode extent tree could be shorter optimise" and multiple "unattached inode connect to lost found" did it for me.